# Vuetify : fixed blocks : left and right

Tags: vuetify.js

In my application, the results page is composed of three blocks :

- left : summary of the search
- middle : results
- right : map of the results

I don't know how to fix the position (position: fixed) of the left and right blocks with Vuetify.

My goal is to keep the left and right blocks displayed while scrolling the list of results (in the middle).

```
<v-content>
  <v-container style="max-width:1264px" class="pa-0">
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs12 sm5 md3 class="">
        <div style="background-color:red;color:white;height:300px">SEARCH FIXED</div>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12 sm7 md4 class="pt-3 pa-2 green">
        RESULTS:<br/> ...
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex class="" xs12 md5>
        <div style="background-color:blue;color:white;height:200px">MAP FIXED</div>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

[Here is the codepen of my application](https://codepen.io/kaboume/pen/pmRdgE)

Comment: https://codepen.io/kaboume/pen/pmRdgE?editors=1111

Comment: If the blocks are fixed, why use the navigation drawer? Why not just use three v-flex with a v-layout set to column?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand ? The navigation drawer is used for the menu. 
I would like that the left and rights blocks of the page don't move when I scroll to the botton. (like the AirBnb Site : the map is fixed to the right and we can scroll the results

Comment: I tried to insert the left block in a navigation drawer but the width of the drawer is not responsive like the v-flex

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Comment: any update to this?